# Comparação de datas corre mal

Tags: java, android

Então eu tenho este código que compara uma data com a data de hoje , mas ás vezes as datas são as seguintes :

```
   D/tag: Sat Jul 22 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017 <<-Data indicada
   D/tag: Sat Jul 22 18:57:17 GMT+01:00 2017 <<-Data de hoje
```

E eu quero que ao fazer isto , o programa não retorne que a data indicada é menor ou seja é uma data anterior a de hoje, eu quero se a data for de hoje que seja indicada como não sendo anterior a data de hoje. O meu código que compara é o seguinte :

```
  if(teste!=null){
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(cyan, teste);
            DatesList.add(teste);
            int ListSize = DatesList.size();
             if(cal.getTime().compareTo(teste)>0){
                 caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(red, teste);
             }
        }
```

Ele neste exemplo que eu indiquei esta a retornar 1.
Cal.getTime() é o tempo presente. "teste" é a data indicada pelo user.

O meu código é o seguinte :

```
    for(int i=1;i <= myDB.getLastId();i++){

        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        String dt = myDB.getDates(i);
            java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date teste = null;

            try {
                teste = sdf.parse(dt);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if(teste!=null){
            Log.d(Tag,""+teste);
            Log.d(Tag,""+cal.getTime());
            Log.d(Tag,""+cal.getTime().compareTo(teste));
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(cyan, teste);
            DatesList.add(teste);
            int ListSize = DatesList.size();
             if(cal.getTime().compareTo(teste)>0){
                 caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(red, teste);
             }
             else if(cal.getTime().compareTo(teste)==0){
                 caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(white,teste);
             }
        }



    }
```

O log esta a dar :

```
    Sat Jul 22 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017
    Sat Jul 22 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017
    1
```

Não percebo porque o cal.getTime().compareTo(teste) esta a retornar 1 quando os valores são claramente iguais!
Obrigado

Comment: Como foi construída a variável `teste` ?

Comment: A variável teste esta no mesmo formato do Cal.getTime() e foi construída a partir de uma dataBase

Comment: Sem o resto do código é difícil de ajudar. A comparação de datas através do `compareTo` de um `Date` funciona bem. Veja [aqui](http://ideone.com/nF4IDe). E também obtinha o mesmo resultado se fosse o `compareTo` de próprio `Calendar` para comparar entre calendarios

Comment: Sim esta funcionando bem , mas o que eu quero é fazer calendar.getTime() para obter, a data do momento , mas queria que as horas minutos e segundos ficassem no 0 e em vez de Sat Jul 22 18:57:17 GMT+01:00 2017 ficasse  Sat Jul 22 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017

Comment: Use o método `set` do `Calendar`. Algo como `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);` , `cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);` e `cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);`

Comment: Ja editei com mais código e o log. Obrigado desde ja.

Comment: Só há uma forma de saber se são mesmo iguais: `Log.d(Tag,""+teste.getTime());` e `Log.d(Tag,""+cal.getTime().getTime());` para ver a representação em milisegundos de cada um.

Comment: Ok irei faze-lo ainda estas ai ?

Comment: O resultado em milissegundo é diferente. Como atuo ? Vou enviar de pronto o resultado. teste = 1500678000000                 cal.getTime()=1500678000198

Comment: @Isac sabe alguma forma de resolver o problema ?

Comment: Só consigo ajudar mais depois de saber como foi construído o `cal`. Independentemente disso uma solução seria passar o `teste` para um calendário e comparar cada parte com `cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)`, e o mesmo para os meses e dias

Comment: O que eu fiz foi cal.set(Calendar.Milisecond,0); e resultou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você compara dois objetos do tipo `Date`, na verdade você está comparando a representação em milissegundos destes objetos.

O método `Date.compareTo(Date anotherDate)` é implementado da seguinte forma:

```
public int compareTo(Date anotherDate) {
    long thisTime = getMillisOf(this);
    long anotherTime = getMillisOf(anotherDate);
    return (thisTime<anotherTime ? -1 : (thisTime==anotherTime ? 0 : 1));
}
```

Repare que ele chama `getMillisOf` faz a comparação utilizando a representação em milissegundos dos dois objetos `Date`.

---

Na linha `Log.d(Tag,""+cal.getTime());`, você *printa* no console um `Date` com o formato `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

Repare que no formato, o campo millisegundos é ignorado. Então, quando você *printou* o `Date`, você não estava vendo sua representação completa.

---

Para resolver seu problema você pode:

### Zerar os campos de minutos, segundos e milissegundos **dos dois** calendars (mais fácil).

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Note que, como você criou a data `teste` com sdf.parse(dt) passando somente `dd-MM-yyyy`, os campos de hora, minuto segundo e milissegundo já estarão zerados.

Desta forma, a verificação `cal.getTime().compareTo(teste)>0` deve funcionar.

### Comparar cada campo dos objetos `Calendar` (mais trabalhoso)

```
if(teste!=null){
    Calendar testeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    testeCal.setTime(teste);

    caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(cyan, teste);
    DatesList.add(teste);
    int ListSize = DatesList.size();

    if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == testeCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) &&
        cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == testeCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) &&
        cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == testeCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Esta abordagem também funciona, mas ela se torna mais trabalhosa para fazer comparações de datas maiores ou menores.